# Query to find count of orders, average value of orders placed by customers, count of orders placed that are greater than a value, in a single query

Tags: mysql

i have a table which have columns- **customer_id**, **order_id**, **order_value**, **city** and **Date**.
I need to find the following all with the help of a Single Query-

1. How many orders has the customer placed in the entire history
2. The average value of orders placed by customers
3. How many orders have been placed that have an **order_value** of more than 5000

I tried the following query

```
select customer_id as Customer,
       count(order_id) as orders,
       avg(order_value) as average_order
       count(case when order_value>5000 then customers.order_value else Null End) as valuegreaterthan5k
       from Customers
       group by Customer;
```

But i am getting errors in implementing the case statements.
Please help on where i am going wrong or i need to alter/replace the case statement completely.

Comment: Your case should be CASE WHEN order_value>5000 then 1 else 0 END. In this way, you count just 1 for the orders greater than 5000.

Comment: " am getting errors in implementing the case statements" - what does that mean?

Comment: Thanks for the help but i am getting this errorERROR 1064 (42000) at line 27: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'count(case when order_value>5000 then 1 else 0 End) as valuegreaterthan5k
      ' at line 4

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: @Hridikalpa because you are missing a comma after average_order :)

Comment: Thanks guys for the help and Thanks @ozan for pointing out what i missed. The query worked fine but will you guys let me know why the  aliases aren't working after i put the case statement?

Comment: @Hridikalpa One of the possible reasons is that you use it at the wrong place. There is an order of processing: GROUP BY precedes SELECT in order of processing; so It doesn't see your alias name! ORDER is like this: FROM (JOIN) --> WHERE --> GROUP BY --> HAVING --> SELECT --> ORDER BY --> LIMIT